Typesetting a 2 times 2 figure grid terminates with error
My M(non)WE is:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{TotalDurationBarPLotArrayList}
\caption{Array list}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{TotalDurationBarPLotLinkedList}
\caption{Array list}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{TotalDurationBarPLotTreeList}
\caption{Array list}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{TotalDurationBarPLotIndexedList}
\caption{Array list}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

pdflatex kindly notifies me with the following error messages:

What am I doing wrong here?

\usepackage{graphicx} with an x not graphics  (with an s)

also replace \end{subfigure} \hfill by \end{subfigure}% as you do not have room for a word space between the figures as they already add up to \textwidth

Please use the graphicx package instead of graphics and also place the subcaption package after graphicx
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
...

